# HashiCorp Vault project - supported encryption algorithms

Tags: encryption, cryptography, private-key, ecdsa, hashicorp-vault

[Vault project](https://www.vaultproject.io/intro/index.html) has feature:

> Data Encryption: Vault can encrypt and decrypt data without storing
>   it. This allows security teams to define encryption parameters and
>   developers to store encrypted data in a location such as SQL without
>   having to design their own encryption methods.

[Transit Secret Backend](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/transit/):

> The transit secret backend handles cryptographic functions on data
>   in-transit. Vault doesn't store the data sent to the backend. It can
>   also be viewed as "cryptography as a service."

1. Does it support ECDSA using secp192r1 curve?
2. `POST /transit/keys/<name>` - creates a new named encryption key of the specified type which later can be used for encryption/decryption or signing/verifying. Does it create key pair of private and public? Is there any method to get/output public key?
3. Is it possible to create custom secret backend which would perform cryptographic operations but would not return private keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer from [Vault project - Jeff](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vault-tool/iEzrai-y8hk):

> ```
>     Does it support ECDSA using secp192r1 curve?
> ```
>
> Not currently.
>
> ```
>     POST /transit/keys/<name> - creates a new named encryption key of the specified type which later can be used for encryption/decryption or signing/verifying. Does it create key pair of private and public? Is there any method to get/output public key?
> ```
>
> If the key type is a public/private type, a read on the key will
>   return the public key.
>
> ```
>     Is it possible to create custom secret backend which would perform cryptographic operations but would not return private keys?
> ```
>
> This is exactly what transit does.